# Is there a difference between using です for some words, or using する to make it a verb?

Tags: nuances

Is there a difference between saying 「[在宅]{ざい・たく}です 」 and 「在宅します」?  Both mean "I'm home/I'm at home," but one is using the intrinsic meaning of「在宅」(at home), and the other is made into a verb meaning to be at home (在宅する).

Answer (score 1):

在宅する is a simple suru-verb. In Japanese, します can describe something in the future. To describe something that is happening now, you have to use its teiru-form:

- 在宅します: Someone will be (staying) at home (in the future)
- 在宅しています: Someone is (staying) at home (now)

On the other hand, 在宅です does not directly show the tense for the action of staying at home. It is more like "[As for me/him/her,] it's '(at) home'". Depending on the context, this may describe someone's current status, someone's future plan, or even someone's past fact. In the context of describing someone's current status, 彼女は在宅です and 彼女は在宅しています are interchangeable. In the context of describing  someone's plan for tomorrow, 彼女は在宅します and 彼女は在宅です are interchangeable.